# What is wrong with this LIKE in an Query?

Tags: soql

i am facing a strange problem using a Like operator in a query.

I want to query fields (String) containing values like 'VG004-0383-543830399298'

Now it seems that the query only delivers results if the LIKE condition contains a non-numeric character.

For example

```
LIKE '%0383%'
```

does not find the entry.

```
LIKE '%-0383%'
```

finds the entry.

Whats wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Johann

Comment: Before querying the results you can remove special characters from the string

Comment: There are no special characters in the string. The problem is that if i include the '-' the record is found, if i search without the '-' the record is not found.